# Where clause to related entity

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, poco

I have a generic repository pattern and I'm trying to load a collection of Agencies based the `FkApplicationId` and if it `IsEnabled == true`

My model looks something like this:
[image]

I thought this would be easy but I can't create a `where` clause to filter the results. I can't see the properties of the `AppAgencies` to write a condition, this is as far as I can get:

```
public IEnumerable<Agency> GetAllEnabledAgencies(int applicationId)
{
    return _agencyRepository.GetMany(m => m.AppAgencies.//No Entity Properties are here);
}
```

From my repository base which is called from above:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
}
```

**Thanks RPM1984, Solution:**

Agencies are consumed by multiple applications, and they need the ability to enable/disable each one per application. So I was using the AppAgency table to tie together that req. because I don't want to have to add a new column to the `Agency` entity every time a new application is introduced.

```
public IEnumerable<Agency> GetAllEnabledAgencies(int applicationId)
{
     return _agencyRepository.GetMany(x => x.AppAgencies.Any(y => y.IsEnabled && y.FkApplicationId == applicationId));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no entity properties because the `AppAgencies` property on `Agency` is a navigational property.

I *think* this is what you want:

```
public IEnumerable<Agency> GetAllEnabledAgencies(int applicationId)
{
    return _agencyRepository.GetMany(x => x.AppAgencies.Any(y => y.IsEnabled));
}
```

In English:

> Get all Agencies, where **at least one** AppAgency is enabled.

If you want:

> Get all Agencies, where **all** AppAgency is enabled.

Change `Any` to `All`.

Comment: Hmm thats really close to what I need. I updated my question with some more information. Either way, you already helped me out tremendously.

Comment: @Jisaak - nps. Don't really understand what query you want though, not sure why your trying to filter on the FkAkencyId for the application id. Shouldn't you just filter on the Agency PK itself? (e.g AgencyId)

Comment: Wow, i guess working late every day has done its toll on me (well thats my story and I'm sticking to it). I def meant to be comparing it against the `FkApplicationId`. I changed the `where` clause and it works perfect. Thanks again! Really helped me out. Thanks!

Comment: @Jisaak - pleasure! Glad you got it sorted.